# How to restrict access to the Apache Solr admin UI based on IP address?

Tags: solr, jetty

I am using Apache Solr 7.7.2.  The jetty version is 9.4.14.

How can I restrict access to the Apache Solr admin UI based on IP address?

In Apache Solr 6.x, this was very easy.  It only required dropping a few lines of XML into jetty.xml.  In Apace Solr 7.x, it appears securing the admin UI might require learning several new concepts.  Is there a way to do it that doesn't require so much intimacy with Solr's plugin system?  Is it required that I upload something to zookeeper just to whitelist some IPs?

Comment: What is the exact configuration that worked in 6x that you are saying is not working in 7x?

Comment: This approach worked in 6x:  https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-To-Secure-Solr-by-IP-Address-td4304491.html

Comment: In 7x, the same XML blocks all traffic, and I am not able to white list my own IP.

Comment: Full disclosure, I have not done this before. Take a look at "-Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.includes" property in the /solr/bin/solr.cmd. https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/bin/solr.cmd

Comment: "solr.jetty.inetaccess.includes" and "solr.jetty.inetaccess.excludes" properties exist in /etc/jetty.xml. May be try configuring them and give it a shot. https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/server/etc/jetty.xml

Comment: REM IP-based access control
set IP_ACL_OPTS=-Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.includes="%SOLR_IP_WHITELIST%" ^
-Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.excludes="%SOLR_IP_BLACKLIST%"

This exist in /solr/bin/solr.cmd

Comment: "May be try configuring them".  How?  I could start dropping my IP into various places in the XML and hope I get lucky, but is there a working example?  Thanks.

Comment: I have not done this before. I just looked at the implementation. They look like                 
"set IP_ACL_OPTS=-Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.includes="%SOLR_IP_WHITELIST%""  
%SOLR_IP_WHITELIST% is a system variable. Try setting such a variable before you start Solr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209533/discussion-between-arnoldbird-and-winniedapooh).